# Stable 200uA Current source by cascading REF200's Current source and Current mirror

Tags: sensor, current-source, voltage-reference, ph

[image: ISFET readout circuit]

I am trying to work on above circuit. A common operating point of ISFET pH sensor is a drain-source current of 100 uA and a drain-source voltage of 500 mV. I am using REF200 current source to feed 100uA i.e. 'I' and for 2I, I am cascading REF200's another current source and current mirror to generate 200uA as shown below.
[image]

I am unable to maintain I and 2I constant. Could experts please help me understand why isn't it working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How constant was your reading? You need to provide more information including how you measured the current and what you measured it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not using the REF200 correctly:

You connect the two 100 uA **current sources in series**, current sources in series is a **big NO-NO** in electronics (unless you don't care about the actual currents).

Suppose one current source wants 100.00 uA to flow but the other one wants 100.05 uA to flow, what will the current be? (the 100.00 uA source will usually win but that is besides the point). Just **don't** connect current sources in series. To **sum** (add up) the currents, just connect the current sources **in parallel**.

The way you use the current mirror is at least a bit odd as you take the output current from the mirror common. Not impossible if you take care that the mirror can work (has the right voltages etc.) just a bit odd.

To make the 200 uA you need, you can also just connect the two current sources **in parallel**.

I do not (yet) see a way how to make the one 100uA (I) and a 200 uA (2I) from **one** REF200. I think you need two of them:

- use one current source for the 100 uA
- use two current sources in parallel for the 200 uA
- do not use the current mirrors at all

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie for the solution. I am going with 2 sources in parallel for 200uA.